# SQLite DB all of a sudden loading duplicate rows for all the tables?

Tags: sqlite, datatable

I have several tables in an sqlite database and its started doing some strange things.  Each time I load the tables now, it's exactly double the length it actually is.  It loads the table once, then once it reaches the end, it loads the table again, creating 2 rows for each item.  So for instance, in a 32 row table, it shows up as 64 rows, with Row 0 and row 32 being the same, row 1 and row 33 being the same, etc...

It does this now for ALL the tables, what is going on and how do I prevent this?

I don't think there is anything in my code that could do this because it has been working fine for a long time until recently.  Her is the load table function I use:

```
Public Sub LoadTable(dbName As String, dt As DataTable, tableName As String,
                         Optional ByVal myFilePath As String = "")
        Dim Conn As New SQLiteConnection()
        GetConnectionString(dbName, Conn, myFilePath)
        Using Conn
            Dim SQLCmd = New SQLiteCommand("Select * From " & tableName)
            Dim DA = New SQLiteDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
            DA.SelectCommand.Connection = Conn
            DA.Fill(dt)
            Conn.Close()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

Can anyone help me get to the bottom of this?  I've verified in the tables themselves, there are no duplicate rows and that this is somehow being generated by .NET when it loads them...

Comment: Show the code that initially fills the tables.

Comment: The tables are being loaded, they are already made, they all have the correct number of rows in the table

Comment: What do you mean with "being loaded"?

Comment: It means the tables have already been created from a while ago, are not created in code when the project runs, and are being loaded from the hard drive.  The same tables worked fine running the same code for a long time.